# Merging more than two images uses too much memory, why?

Tags: uiimage, instruments, cgcontext

I can't figure out why using GCContext, for drawing/merging more than two UIImages, uses so
much memory. I have ARC enabled and when looking at my programs memory usage in Instruments (with the VM Tracker tool) I see that the first solution below uses only memory for two images (about 16 MB DirtySize and 80 MB ResidentSize), whereas drawing in a CGContext uses the amount of memory for all my UIImages (about 468 MB DirtySize and 520 MB ResidentSize) and finally causes my app to crash.
How can I make sure the CGContext doesn't use more than the amount of memory used for the
two UIImages?
Actually I like to accomplish a kind of double-buffering for drawing multiple layers of the same size of image-files (.PNG based and already have a transparent setting) with minimal memory requirements and optimal performance.

Note that my ViewController contains an 'UIImageView *imageView' and a 'CGSize imageSize'
property.

The following code is being used for only checking the amount of memory consumed by loading the UIImages:

```
- (void)drawUsingTwoUIImages1:(NSMutableArray *)imageFiles
{
    if ( ! imageFiles.count ) {
        return;
    }
    NSString *imageFile1 = [imageFiles objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:imageFile1 ofType:nil];
    UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath1];
    UIImage *image2 = nil;
    image1 = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath1];
    for (NSInteger index = 1; index < imageFiles.count; index++) {
        NSString *imageFile2 = [imageFiles objectAtIndex:index];
        NSString *filePath2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:imageFile2 ofType:nil];
        image2 = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath2];
    }
}
```

The next code I'ld like to use in my final app in order to show all imageFiles drawn. I suspect that some clever trick needs to be done in the order of CGContext handling or probably a CGLayerRef one. If anybody can show me how to do this, or come up with working
code I'll be in coding haven again!

```
- (void)drawUsingTwoUIImages2:(NSMutableArray *)imageFiles
{
    _imageView.image = nil;
    if ( ! imageFiles.count ) {
        return;
    }
    NSString *imageFile1 = [imageFiles objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:imageFile1 ofType:nil];
    UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath1];
    UIImage *image2 = nil;
    for (NSInteger index = 1; index < imageFiles.count; index++) {
        if ( ! UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() ) {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(_imageSize);
        }
        NSString *imageFile2 = [imageFiles objectAtIndex:index];
        NSString *filePath2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:imageFile2 ofType:nil];
        image2 = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath2];
        [image1 drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0., 0.)];
        [image2 drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0., 0.)];
        image1 = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }
    _imageView.image = image1;
}
```

The above really drives me nuts and does anybody see here what I'm missing, or know what to do to get maximum performance and minimum memory usage?!

Comment: Figure out any good pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already figured out that the way to go is using CATiledLayer and where needed tile your image data in various scale-sizes. Digging around in Apple's example code and searching in StackOverflow helped me to solve this issue.